# Git subfolders that are git repos themselves

Tags: git

Two fold question really.

- Is there a way for git to include/track a folder but ignore what's going on in it regarding git commands? That way I could cd into a folder and do a git pull on that repo only.

or, maybe a better way

- Submodules - How can I add a submodule to git and have it commit all files that belong to submodules. Now, when/if I add a submodule that directory is empty in repo - but I really need all of the files from submodules to be in the repo as well. Of course, I don't want to lose ability to update/pull newer versions of submodules.

edit: Found the solution to what I needed. Apparently I was looking for git subtrees.

Comment: Why do you think you need all the submodule files to be in the top-level repository?

Comment: I don't. Also, in the meantime, I found the solution that suits me. Subtrees are what I was looking for.